# Garmin G1000 'Waves in a Circle' Symbol?

Tags: avionics, g1000, symbology

we had this symbol come up on a G1000 and could not find a reference for what it indicates. Could anyone tell me what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

It's a county flood warning:

[image]

> **COUNTY WARNINGS**
>
> County data (Figure 6-38) provides specific public awareness and protection weather warnings from the National Weather Service (NWS). This can include information on tornadoes, severe thunderstorms, and flood conditions.
>
> **Displaying County Warning information:**
>
> **1)** Select the Weather Data Link (XM) Page.
>
> **2)** Press the MORE WX Softkey.
>
> **3)** Press the COUNTY Softkey.
>
> To display the County Warnings legend (Figure 6-39), press the **LEGEND** Softkey when County Warnings are selected to be displayed.

[G1000 Pilot's Guide for Cessna Nav III](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/190-00498-07_0A_Web.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwijt6325pz5AhVFCewKHe36ARkQFnoECAwQAg&usg=AOvVaw1PCya-QXkBVj4EUPJYMgpF) p. 304 (the symbology is the same in all G1000 variants with XM weather and the legend can probably also be found in the Pilot's Guide for your variant if not a Cessna Nav III).

Comment: In other words @Justin, it means you are flying over water where you never expected it, so you may want to divert around in case of an engine failure.